# Ошибка при установке aiogram на ubuntu

Tags: python

Ввожу `sudo pip3 install aiogram`
Выдаёт это:  `Command "python setup.py egg_info" fa iled with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-bu ild-j5ryz5xb/aiohttp/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйnt сначала обновиться.

$ pip3 install --upgrade setuptools

$ pip3 install --upgrade pip